# Markov Model for coin flips

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose that we flip a fair coin and we win when we get for a first time HTH.Is there a way that we can construct a markov model with 4 states ??

Comment: Can you do the problem with more than 4 states? For instance, there's a reasonably straightforward Markov model with 8 states.

Comment: We can do it with $\left \{ H,T \right \}^{3}$.But I can't really see how we can reduce them to 4.

Comment: A markov model for what?  You get to flip forever until $HTH$ occurs?  That will happen with probability $1$ eventually.

Comment: Depending on what you intend to model (not clear to me) I presume the states keep track of how much of $HTH$ you have built up.  Thus the states are attached to $\emptyset, H,HT,HTH$.

Comment: Yes we get to flip until we get for a first time HTH.We may have infinite flips but we only take into account the last three flips.

Comment: I gave you the state space of size $4$.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it a little bit late , but thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Let the set of states be $\{I,H, HT, W\}$. The transitions are as follows:

[image]

And the system starts in $I$.

This is a deterministic machine if we don't consider that the inputs are heads and tails with equal probability. Taking this into account then we can tell that every state transition takes place with probability $\frac12, \frac12$ from the actual state to the two allowed next states. Based on this the state transition probability matrix can be written up.

Comment: Also if I'm correct the initial distribution $\pi_{0}=(1,0,0,0)$ because we necessary start at I ?

Comment: Yes, that is the initial distribution.